# How to calculate percentage with Pandas' DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

How to add another column to Pandas' DataFrame with percentage? The dict can change on size.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> a = {'Test 1': 4, 'Test 2': 1, 'Test 3': 1, 'Test 4': 9}
>>> p = pd.DataFrame(a.items())
>>> p
        0  1
0  Test 2  1
1  Test 3  1
2  Test 1  4
3  Test 4  9

[4 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If indeed percentage of `10` is what you want, the simplest way is to adjust your intake of the data slightly:

```
>>> p = pd.DataFrame(a.items(), columns=['item', 'score'])
>>> p['perc'] = p['score']/10
>>> p
Out[370]: 
     item  score  perc
0  Test 2      1   0.1
1  Test 3      1   0.1
2  Test 1      4   0.4
3  Test 4      9   0.9
```

For real percentages, instead:

```
>>> p['perc']= p['score']/p['score'].sum()
>>> p
Out[427]: 
     item  score      perc
0  Test 2      1  0.066667
1  Test 3      1  0.066667
2  Test 1      4  0.266667
3  Test 4      9  0.600000
```

Comment: I prefer this over joe's version since it is simpler, and as I am not calling any lambdas, faster (I assume).

Comment: Actually, I tried to get real percentages e.g. 9 of 15 = 60 %.

    0  Test 2      1   0.1  6.66, 
    1  Test 3      1   0.1  6.66, 
    2  Test 1      4   0.4  26.66, 
    3  Test 4      9   0.9  60,

Answer (score 7):

First, make the keys of your dictionary the index of you dataframe:

```
 import pandas as pd
 a = {'Test 1': 4, 'Test 2': 1, 'Test 3': 1, 'Test 4': 9}
 p = pd.DataFrame([a])
 p = p.T # transform
 p.columns = ['score']
```

Then, compute the percentage and assign to a new column.

```
 def compute_percentage(x):
      pct = float(x/p['score'].sum()) * 100
      return round(pct, 2)

 p['percentage'] = p.apply(compute_percentage, axis=1)
```

This gives you:

```
         score  percentage
 Test 1      4   26.67
 Test 2      1    6.67
 Test 3      1    6.67
 Test 4      9   60.00

 [4 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Actually, I tried to get real percentages e.g. 9 of 15 = 60 %.

    0  Test 2      1   0.1  6.66, 
    1  Test 3      1   0.1  6.66, 
    2  Test 1      4   0.4  26.66, 
    3  Test 4      9   0.9  60,

Comment: See my edited answer. It sums up the `score` column and takes it as the perfect score as your comment above implies.

Comment: And, no more `lambda` function. I wrote out the complete function for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
 
data = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'B': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# calculate percentage using apply() method and lambda function
 
df['B_Percentage'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: (x / df['B'].sum()) * 100)
 
print(df)
```

using lambda can be useful. can be done by more methods. maybe this will help  http://www.pythonpandas.com/how-to-calculate-the-percentage-of-a-column-in-pandas/

Answer (score 0):

```
df=pd.read_excel("regional cases.xlsx")
df.head()

REGION  CUMILATIVECOUNTS    POPULATION

GREATER         12948       4943075
ASHANTI         4972        5792187
WESTERN         2051        2165241
CENTRAL         1071        2563228



df['Percentage']=round((df['CUMILATIVE COUNTS']/ df['POPULATION']*100)*100,2)
df.head()



REGION  CUMILATIVECOUNTS    POPULATION  Percentage

GREATER 12948               4943075      26.19
ASHANTI 4972                5792187      8.58
WESTERN 2051                2165241      9.47
```

Comment: I think you should describe what you are trying to achieve at least.